# Suggestion for Computing an Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $$A=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{y^4}{4}+\dfrac{z^6}{6}\leq1\right\}.$$

Then I want to compute the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(A)}\displaystyle\int_{\partial A}^{}\!\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^{10}}}\, d(x,y,z)$$

Should I use spherical coordinates or something like that?

I am a beginner to this topic, so any help would be nice.

Edit: I put the factor $\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(A)}$ before the integral (that's exactly my task now), but there should be no different concerning our problem...

$$I := \frac{1}{\lambda_3(A)} \int\limits_{\partial A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^6 + z^{10}}} \, dS_{\partial A}$$

Comment: Do you really mean to have $dx$ at the end of the integral?

Comment: No, I just correct it, thanks

Comment: Cool looking surface!

Comment: My guess right now would be an application of the Divergence Thoerem in lieu of computing the surface integral.

Comment: @semiclassical, that's an interesting idea, but I'm worried it will be hard to find a good vector field $F$ and the surface will still be bad

Comment: @TylerHG, we search for $F$ such that $\nabla \cdot F = ...$, then use divergence to get a surface integral.

Comment: There are two competing factors here. One is to get the bounds nice, the other to get the integrand nice. For the just the first octant portion, picking $x=2^{1/2}\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$, $y=2 (\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta)^{1/2}$, and $z=6^{1/6}(\rho\cos \phi)^{1/3}$ gives the nice bounds $0\leq \rho \leq 1$, $0\leq \phi,\theta \leq \pi/2$, but the integrand is a mess. I haven't computed the Jacocian either.

Comment: Right. Finding a vector field whose normal derivative at the surface is nice seems painful.

Comment: Another route might be to look for a substitution like $(x,y,z)\to(x^r,y^p,z^q)$. Though I don't know whether it's smarter to make the integrand nice or the bounds nice.

Comment: Where did this problem come from @Xtk ?

Comment: it is a homework

Comment: A textbook? @Xtk

Comment: No, just an exercise sheet :/

Comment: And I think you guys are right. I think we have to determine a certain vector field, because we recently proved that theorem in the lecture.

Comment: One thing that makes the Divergence Theorem slightly tricky to apply in this fashion is it's evaluated on the surface, i.e $x^2/2+$etc$=1$. So $\nabla F \cdot \mathbf{n}$ may be rather disguised right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the normal vector of $A's$ boundary is $\hat{n}=\frac{(x, y^3, z^5)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^10}}$. Then we choose $F(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{4},\frac{z}{6})$, on the boundary, we have $$F\cdot \hat{n}=\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{z^6}{6}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^{10}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^{10}}}$$ So the integral

$$\frac{1}{vol(A)}\int_{\partial A}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^{10}}}ds=\frac{1}{vol(A)}\int_{\partial A} F\cdot \hat{n} ds=\frac{1}{vol(A)}\int_{ A}\nabla\cdot F dxdydz  \quad= \frac{1}{vol(A)}\int_{ A} \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{11}{12}$$

Comment: That's the exact kind of answer I was hoping someone would provide rather than some complicated special-functions route. (+1)

Comment: Very nice answer (+1) I feel a bit stupid :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. thats what i wanted! Could you explain me how you get that normal vector?

Comment: Haha, you are welcome. I saw @Seyed Mohsen Ayyoubzadeh, the third answerer, have already shown the process of how to find the normal vector, so I just skipped it. We know if $F(x,y,z)=0$ is boundary curve, then $(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial z})$ is in the same direction as the normal vector, so just normalize it by dividing by its length.

Answer (score 9):

Let us express the surface element in terms of $y,z$:
$$dS=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \right)^2} \,dy dz,\tag{1}$$
where 
$$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{z^6}{6}=1. \tag{2}$$
Now from (2) it follows that
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=-\frac{y^3}{x},\qquad \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=-\frac{z^5}{x},$$
and therefore the formula (1) transforms into
$$dS=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^6+z^{10}}}{|x|}dydz.$$
The surface integral we want to compute (without the inverse volume prefactor) then becomes
$$I_S=4\sqrt{2}\iint_D\frac{dydz}{\sqrt{\displaystyle1-\frac{y^4}{4}-\frac{z^6}{6}}},$$
where $\displaystyle D=\left\{(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{z^6}{6}\leq1,y\geq0,z\geq0\right\}$. Next define
$$a=\frac{y^2}{2},\qquad b=\frac{z^3}{\sqrt{6}}\qquad
\Longleftrightarrow \qquad y=\sqrt{2a},\qquad z=6^{\frac16}b^{\frac13}$$
and rewrite the integral as
$$I_S=8\cdot 6^{-5/6}\iint_{D'}\frac{a^{-1/2}b^{-2/3}dadb}{\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}},$$
with $$D'=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2:a^2+b^2\leq 1,a\geq0,b\geq0\}.$$
Now it becomes helpful to introduce polar coordinates $a=r\cos\theta,b=r\sin\theta$ and rewrite the integral as
$$I_S=8\cdot 6^{-5/6}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{r^{-1/6}dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}_{I_1}\;\underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta)^{-1/2}(\sin\theta)^{-2/3}d\theta}_{I_2}.$$
It is not difficult to express $I_{1,2}$ in terms of gamma functions:
$$I_1=-6\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{12})}{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{12})},\qquad
I_2=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(\frac14)\Gamma(\frac16)}{\Gamma(\frac5{12})},$$
and therefore
$$\boxed{\displaystyle I_S=-24\sqrt{\pi}\cdot 6^{-5/6}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})}{\Gamma(-\frac{1}{12})}}\tag{3}$$

---

The volume of $A$ can be computed very similarly. Indeed, 
\begin{align}\operatorname{vol}A&=\iiint_A dx dy dz=\\&=8\sqrt2\iint_D \sqrt{\displaystyle1-\frac{y^4}{4}-\frac{z^6}{6}} \,dy dz=\\&=
16\cdot 6^{-5/6}\iint_{D'}a^{-1/2}b^{-2/3}\sqrt{1-a^2-b^2}\,dadb=\\
&=16\cdot 6^{-5/6}\cdot I_2\cdot \int_0^1 r^{-1/6}\sqrt{1-r^2}dr=\\
&=16\cdot 6^{-5/6}\cdot I_2\cdot\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4}\frac{\Gamma(\frac5{12})}{\Gamma(\frac{23}{12})},
\end{align}
so that
$$\boxed{\displaystyle I=\frac{I_S}{\operatorname{vol}A}=\frac{11}{12}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the $4\sqrt{2}$ constant in front of the integral. Should it be $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @TylerHG Additional symmetry factor $8$ comes from the condition $x,y,z\geq 0$.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't account for $x$ @O.L.

Comment: Could just leave it as a beta function @O.L.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: I suspect that you should use the Divergence theorem. First, note that the normal vector to the surface under consideration ($\partial A$) is$$\begin{array}{c}\hat n = \frac{{\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}},\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}},\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}} \right)}^2}} }}\\ = \frac{{\left( {x,{y^3},{z^5}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^6} + {z^{10}}} }}\end{array}$$Note that the denominator is already present in your question.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is the correct way to go: the beta function method may be correct, but it's probably far more circuitous than finding a direct Divergence Theorem approach.